# Radio button default checked not working because of JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have a list of radio buttons binded to a checkbox in the following manner.
1) When the checkbox is checked, the radio buttons are enabled and have a default button checked (say value=1) (only one radio button can be selected out of the three)
2) When the checkbox is unchecked, the radio buttons are disabled and their selection attribute is removed.

The problem that I'm facing is that due to the following HTML and Jquery code, the default selection of radio button on page load (value=1) is not working. I've not been able to identify the error. Can somebody please helpout?

```js
$('#mailcheck').change(function() {
  $('input[name="freq"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  $('input[name="freq"]').removeAttr('checked');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="notcheck">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mailcheck" checked="checked">I want to receive an email notification of ads uploaded on my college marketplace
</label>
<br>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="freq" value="1" id="freqradio" checked="checked">Daily</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="freq" value="3" id="freqradio">Every 3 days</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="freq" value="7" id="freqradio">Weekly</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't call `.change()` at the end. That's running the handler, and it removes all the `checked` attributes.

Comment: Why are you removing the `checked` property of the disabled radio-inputs? If they're disabled they won't be submitted to the server, and if someone unchecks by accident it's (usually) irritating to that user to have to re-check something. Especially if the same functionality is repeated throughout the form.

Comment: That works, but only partially. The radio button should get selected whenever the checkbox is checked. How do I ensure that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a rough working version:

```js
$('#mailcheck').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name="freq"]').prop('disabled', false).first().prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[name="freq"]').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="notcheck">
 <input type="checkbox" id="mailcheck" checked="checked" >I want to receive an email notification of ads uploaded on my college marketplace
</label><br>

  <ul>
   <li><label><input type="radio" name="freq" value="1" id="freqradio1" checked="checked">Daily</label></li>
   <li><label><input type="radio" name="freq" value="3" id="freqradio2">Every 3 days</label></li>
   <li><label><input type="radio" name="freq" value="7" id="freqradio3">Weekly</label></li>
  </ul>
```

p.s. the ids must have an unique value

Comment: Why copy to jsfiddle instead of using a stack snippet here?